# Why does my Axios get request fail but works when I use a online REST test tool?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am  trying to do a Axios request but when I do. I get the error "[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403]" This is strange as when I put that token and api_url into a online REST Get request it works and returns output. This was pulled from my friends Git and for him it works and returns a response and not a error. So I am wondering why Axios isn't working for me.

```
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { getSpotifyToken } from "../../hooks/spotifyAuth";
import { setSpotifyToken } from "../../hooks/spotifyAuth";

const getTopArtists = async () => {
  //Getting spotify token
  const spotifyToken = getSpotifyToken();
  console.log("Getting access Token for TopSongs:", spotifyToken);
  const api_url =
    "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?time_range=medium_term&limit=5";

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(api_url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${spotifyToken}`,
      },
    });

    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data.items;
  } catch (error) {
    setSpotifyToken("");

    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: is your token logged in console ?

Comment: yes the token logs. the token that logs is valid and I was able to use on a online GET site.

Comment: spotifyToken is not a state variable, right?

Comment: No the spotifyToken isn't a state variable